# Jquery .resize() won`t trigger my function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I coded JS function too make responsive HTML list menu by nesting items starting from 3rd item into submenu using `clone` and `append`.

```
<div class="menu-header-menu-container">
 <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="navigation">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  .....
 </ul>
</div>
```

Once, I included `.resize` to trigger the function each time browser window is being re-sized, I found the function won`t trigger

```
$(window).resize(function() {
 if ($(window).width() < 640) {
  $(function () {
  var lis = $('.menu-header-menu-container ul li:gt(0)').clone();
  $('.menu-header-menu-container ul li:gt(0)').remove();
  var newLI = $('<li class="toggle-dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)">المزيد +</a></li>')
  var newUL = $('<ul class="nested"></ul>');
  $('.menu-header-menu-container ul').append(newLI);
  $( ".toggle-dropdown a" ).append(newUL);
  newUL.append(lis);
});
} else if ($(window).width() > 640) {
  $(function () {
  var lis_old = $('.menu-header-menu-container ul.nested').clone();
  $( ".toggle-dropdown", "ul.nested" ).remove();
  $('.menu-header-menu-container ul').append(lis_old);
  // alert("Hello");
  });
}
});
```

Code snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/3o32rj1m/

Any help to fix this issue is much appreciated :)

Comment: Other than creating an infinite loop and crashing the browser, it works just fine for me

Comment: logic bug: what about `window.width = 640`?

Comment: why are you using js to make your site responsive? use css media queries.

Comment: @Cruiser CSS won`t nest list items according to index order. Bootstrap for example nest all items which is easy to be handled using only CSS.

Comment: the above code works perfectly fine

Comment: @Sumit How come, the code snippet I shared is obviously not triggering the function?!

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim It is triggering. check this https://jsfiddle.net/3o32rj1m/1/

Comment: @Sumit Still have newUL.append(lis); not working with .resize(), Any suggestions?

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim honestly, i didn't full understand what you are looking for. See this if that is what you want https://jsfiddle.net/3o32rj1m/6/ else kindly brief your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS destroy triggered function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213908/js-destroy-triggered-function)