# JS destroy triggered function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I coded JS code to restructure html list items for responsive usage:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 640) {
        $(function resizenav() {
            var lis = $('.menu-header-menu-container ul li:gt(1)').clone();
            $('.menu-header-menu-container ul li:gt(1)').remove();
            var newLI = $('<li class="toggle-dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)">more+</a></li>')
            var newUL = $('<ul class="nested"></ul>');
            $('.menu-header-menu-container ul').append(newLI);
            $(".toggle-dropdown a").append(newUL);
            newUL.append(lis);
        });
    } else if ($(window).width() > 640) {
        //destroy function resizenav()
    }
});
```

Code snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/3o32rj1m/3/

I am seeking a way to destroy `resizenav()` and restore back the navigation original html structure. Any help is much appreciated?

Comment: Why are you wrapping the function in `jQuery`? I would cache the original html and modified in memory or `sessionStorage` then you can toggle between them, at will

Comment: @colecmc Could you share some code snippet?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question about destroying the function, but here is an example about my `sessionStorage` suggestion. https://output.jsbin.com/davizu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution too... sorry for the delay. Here's the gist:

```
var isSmall = false;

$(window).on('load resize', function(){
  if(!isSmall && $(window).width() <= 640){
    var extraListItems = $('#menu-header-menu > li:gt(1)');
    if(extraListItems.size() > 0){
      var subList = $('<ul>').addClass('nested-list').append(extraListItems).css('display', 'none');
      var toggle = $('<li>').addClass('toggle-nested-list').append("<span class='toggle-text'>more+</span>")
      .on('click', function(){
        subList.toggle();
        if(subList.is(':visible')){ $(this).find('.toggle-text').text('less-'); }
        else{ $(this).find('.toggle-text').text('more+'); }
      });
      toggle.append(subList).appendTo('#menu-header-menu');
    }
    isSmall = true;
  }
  else if(isSmall && $(window).width() > 640){
    var listItems = $('#menu-header-menu .nested-list li');
    listItems.appendTo('#menu-header-menu');
    $('#menu-header-menu .toggle-nested-list').remove();
    isSmall = false;
  }
});
```

Hopefully I didn't miss anything when copying and pasting my code from jsFiddle, but I've got it all there for sure, with comments. Make sure you just resize the output frame in jsFiddle, as resizing the entire browser window has some strange effects there... https://jsfiddle.net/m4n41wkc/

Comment: Very much ideal solution. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var flag = false;
var original = $('.menu-header-menu-container ul').clone().html();
function resizenav() {
    var lis = $('.menu-header-menu-container ul li:gt(1)').clone();
    $('.menu-header-menu-container ul li:gt(1)').remove();
    var newLI = $('<li class="toggle-dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)">more+</a></li>')
    var newUL = $('<ul class="nested"></ul>');
    $('.menu-header-menu-container ul').append(newLI);
    $( ".toggle-dropdown a" ).append(newUL);
    newUL.append(lis);
};

$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 640) {
        if(!flag) {
            resizenav();
            flag = true;
        }
    } else if ($(window).width() > 640) {
        if(flag){
            $('.menu-header-menu-container ul').html(original);
            flag = false;
        }
    }
});
```